# What is difference between autowiring vs dependency injection in Spring?

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring can anyone tell me What is difference between autowiring vs dependency injection in Spring ?

I tried to search on internet but I dont find things much helpful.

Comment: It's the same thing. The term "autowiring" comes from the use of the `@Autowired` annotation, which just a marker annotation for the DI container to inject the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. When the concept was new, there were several names used, and "dependency injection" ended up becoming the most common. Spring's configuration system used "autowire", and that's stuck around there, and the GoF term "inversion of control" is sometimes used, usually in a more academic setting. They're all synonyms.